# Subject and beneficiary of 〜くれる

Tags: grammar, giving-and-receiving

I can't completely understand the meaning of くれる in the following dialogues. In the first example, if I'm understanding, it is something like this:

> せっかく**ミストリアはエルドに**こう言ってくれているんだし

So the one who gains something is エルド and the subject is ミストリア.

In the second dialogue my loose translation is - "I would be satisfied if by using this barter shop, you would gain even more than you expect".

However I can't completely understand; does 主人公 gain even more profit (想定の上をいって), but thankful (くれた) for it will be 店長?

1st dialogue

> ミストリア「私が決めていいのならば・・・・・・」
>
> ミストリア「エルド、お前の好きに指示を出して見てはどうだ」
>
> エルド「えぇ！？」
>
> ラヴィリエ「へえ、それは面白そうね」
>
> エルド「ラヴィリエまで」
>
> ラヴィリエ「せっかくこう**言ってくれている**んだし、お言葉に甘えてみたら？いざという時にわたしたちでどうにかするから」

2nd dialogue

> 店長「ここを預かる者としては、お前のような存在にこそこの地を活用して欲しいと思っているのも事実」
>
> 店長「どこぞの勇者と呼ばれるような奴には、ここなど何の価値もない場所かもしれんしな」
>
> 店長「この交換所を利用することで想定の上を**いってくれた**なら本望だ」
>
> 主人公「頑張ります。」

Comment: The whole "2nd dialogue" souns so unreal -- the way 店長 speaks.  I cannot even picture the scene.  The only 交換所 I have seen in my life have been located right next to pachinko parlors.  Is this happening on OUR planet?  I could probably post a decent answer if I tried but I just cannot empathize with the dialogue.

Comment: It's from a game, and not even on our planet, so no wonders it sounds so unreal.

Comment: 「利用することで想定の上を」>> Is it not 「利用すること **を** 想定の上 **で** 」?

Comment: @Choko, it is just as I written. I thought that this 上をいってくれた - [上を行って](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%B8%8A%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F-438483)くれた

Comment: Ah so it's 想定の上を行く, 想定を超える

Comment: Could you briefly explain the context of the second dialogue? What is the 主人公 doing on that land? How is 勇者 related to this story?

Comment: 主人公 is one of the participants of a tournament or something like this. In one of the previous lines 店長 said to him that he doesn't look as strong as the other participants. I think that by 勇者 he mean other guys, who actually look strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

くれる, as an auxiliary verb, indicates that the main verb action is done for the speaker or that the speaker is grateful.

> せっかくミストリアが君（のため）にこう言ってくれているんだし

I'd say the best explanation here is that the speaker ラヴィリエ takes the point of view of エルド, or that she(?) emphasizes with him. ミストリア is saying it for the good of エルド.

> この交換所を利用することで想定の上をいってくれたなら本望だ

想定の上を行く does not have the 主人公 as the subject, but it will (hopefully) be caused by him (or her).

It benefits the speaker (店長) in some way, tangible (physically) or intangible (emotionally).

He says he would be glad if the weaker 主人公 were to use the 交換所, and not some どこぞの勇者, who is already strong enough and couldn't make good use of it anyways. He lets him use the shop, which he hopes will allow the 主人公 to claim a rank in the tournament to be proud of.

He might get part of the price money if the 主人公 does well. But money probably isn't the only thing that interests him and he's also proud of his shop and glad he found somebody who can make good use of his shop and services. If the 主人公 gets a good rank, the 店長 will be proud too. And it might get him some free PR.

At any rate it benefits the 店長 as he clearly says he wants it for some reason.

Comment: With the updated information, I think this answer explains the situation more clearly. As a side note, 「想定の上をいく」 in this case is to have a better result in the tournament than expected. Also, the reason why the 店長 talks about どこぞの勇者 is because he thinks the 勇者 is strong enough and doesn't need to use the 交換所.

Comment: @NigoroJr Thanks, I updated the answer. Pretty much the perfect example why context is needed even when we don't realize it is...